# Create separate CSS files in postcss & rollup

Tags: css, build, rollupjs, postcss

I want each `css` file I import in my JS to create a new css file for my build. For instance:

```js
import "./app.css";
import "./admin.css";
```

would create `dist/app.css` and `dist/admin.css`. I am using rollup and here is my config file:

```js
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import { terser } from "rollup-plugin-terser";

import postcssImport from "postcss-import";
import postcssNested from "postcss-nested";
import autoprefixer from "autoprefixer";

const dev = process.env.WP_ENV === "development";

export default {
  input: "src/main.js",
  output: {
    sourcemap: dev,
    format: "iife",
    name: "main",
    file: "dist/main.bundle.js",
  },
  plugins: [
    resolve({
      browser: true,
    }),
    postcss({
      plugins: [postcssImport(), postcssNested(), autoprefixer()],
      extract: true,
      sourceMap: "inline",
      minimize: !dev,
    }),
    commonjs(),
    !dev && terser(),
  ],
  watch: {
    clearScreen: false,
  },
};
```

Comment: I would be very much interested in the answer as well...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has not been documented but you can use `include`, `exclude` according to [their source code](https://github.com/egoist/rollup-plugin-postcss/blob/6480f02681d1526c102f3e99891b788d01031f32/src/index.js#L43).

An example here for two css files:

```
import { resolve } from "path"
```

```
plugins: [
  postcss({
    include: "**/admin.css",
    extract: resolve('dist/admin.css')
  }),
  postcss({
    include: "**/app.css",
    extract: resolve('dist/app.css')
  })
]
```

And if you want to exclude one file:

```
plugins: [
  postcss({
    exclude: "**/bootstrap.css",
    extract: resolve('dist/app.css')
  }),
  postcss({
    include: "**/bootstrap.css",
    extract: resolve('dist/bootstrap.css')
  })
]
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Rollup is 1.32.1.

Answer (score 3):

I created a plugin - [rollup-plugin-lib-style](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-lib-style) that generates CSS separately for every style file and imports these generated CSS files (as CSS modules).

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up with

```js
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
```

```js
plugins: [
  external(),
  resolve(),
  commonjs(),
  typescript(),
  postcss({
    include: "src/index.css",
    extract: "index.css",
    minimize: true,
    sourceMap: true,
  }),
  postcss({
    include: "src/themes/file2.css",
    extract: "themes/file2.css",
    minimize: true,
    sourceMap: true,
  }),
  terser(),
]
```